# Jenkins - Only Admin can log in. No options to Sign in or Sign up

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins version 2.264. After the installation I always get `Unlock Jenkins` page and there is no other options for users to sign up or sign in. I've selected `Allow users to sign up` but still I don't see a login page..

[image]

Comment: That's pretty much always there the first time you connect to the server unless you go the Jenkins Configuration-as-code route and setup/turn off the credentials in advance

Comment: How can I enable login page? I've been using the Unlock jenkins to configure everything but now I want other users to be able to login

Answer (score 1):

After installing `Role-based Authorization Strategy` plugin, the login page started to show up.